# Обновление страницы

Tags: ajax, django

Есть небольшие наработки [камеры](http://websint.ru/) необходимо при нажатии на камеру1 или камера2 подгружалась камера не обновляя всю страницу.

Answer (score 1):

Можно менять на ходу часть страницы через innerHTML

Comment: Или через аналог в `jQuery`. `Django` тут, в общем-то, и ни при чем

Comment: Если не сложно можно пример.

Comment: document.getElementById('jwplayer').innerHTML = 'и тут вычисляете новые значения параметров плеера';